# Primefaces 3.0.M4 IE 7. CheckAll checkbox not working

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using Primefaces 3.0.M4, 12/1/2011 build with JSF 2.0, web application. CheckAll checkbox in table header to toggle multiple selection checkboxes does not work in any browsers i tested in. I tried it in IE7, Firefox 5.0 in windows. Firefox 7 in ubuntu. No luck.

```
<p:dataTable id="blocksTable"
    var="block" value="#{splitBlockBean.blockDataModel}" 
    selection="#{splitBlockBean.selectedBlocks}"
    scrollable="true" scrollHeight="230" scrollWidth="410">  

    <p:column selectionMode="multiple"/>

    <p:column style="width:300px;" headerText="Subnet Address">
        #{block.label}
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Now, If I remove scrollbars around this table, it works fine. But not with scrollbars. I need scrollbars as this table can display records upto 256 and users wants to able to select all at one go without having to use paginator.

Interesting aspect I found in datatable.js is that JQuery does not return checkAllToggler checkbox if the table is surrounded by a scrollbar. Here's is the snippet from datatable.js

```
this.checkAllToggler = $(this.jqId + ' > table thead th.ui-selection-column input:checkbox');
this.checkAllToggler.bind('click', function() {
    _self.toggleCheckAll();
});
```

Any help is apprecaited.

Comment: Interesting... there may be a fundamental reason why this is not being returned, or it just may be an oversight.  Either way, it seems like a bug.  You can log the issue here: http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/list

Comment: If you write this up I will vote for it BTW

Comment: Thanks. I wish there was way to not have header checkAll checkbox. This way, I could override/implement my own toggle functionality.

Comment: I understand that, but keep in mind that implementing scrollbars with fixed headers in an AJAX-enabled datatable web component is a notoriously hard thing to do.  I can't recall a single JSF datatable or ASP.NET web control datatable that was able to do this without some kind of bugginess.

Comment: You can hide toggle checkAll checkbox by css.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a recent 3.0.RC1 build, more info http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=1552

Comment: I tried with that as well. Infact I posted exact same question on primefaces forums as well and received same suggession. It did not work with RC1. I am falling back on instant selection or perhaps as you suggested hide checkAll box and use my custom selection strategy.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong in your environment, it works for me.

Comment: Thanks Cagatay. I switched to using instant selection without checkboxes. But would you please post the code you tested. I am curious if I can get that to work as well. Thanks again.